# Figuring out which response belongs to which request using proxpy

Tags: python, http, proxy, http-proxy

I am writing a plugin for proxpy (you don't need to be familiar with it to answer this question). This is basically an HTTP/HTTPS proxy. You extend it by implementing two functions, the arguments to which is the HTTP request and response respectively. Something like this:

```
method1(request):  
    #your implementation

method2(response):  
    #your implementation
```

I want to simply write the requests and responses to a file in the following format.

```
Request 1  
Response of request 1  
Request 2  
Response of request 2.  
#etc
```

However, the requests and responses might not necessarily in an order so they are written something like this:

```
Request 1  
Request 2  
Response of request 2  
Request 3  
Response of request 3  
Response of request 2
```

So, in essence, what I want to do is find out which request each response corresponds to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like the following code which stores each request in a dictionary keyed by thread id, and then matches the response using the same thread id. This relies on the fact that `proxpy` uses a separate worker thread for each request and response pair (something that requires knowledge of the `proxpy` implementation!).

Note that exceptions raised outside of the plugin code will result in "orphaned" requests in the `sent` dictionary, although this might not be such a problem if thread ids are reused (as observed in practise).

Also, the output of this plugin will be to log paired requests and responses, but the order will be that of reception of the response, not necessarily in the order sent.

```
import threading

lock = threading.Lock()
sent = {}
req_seq = 0

def proxy_mangle_request(req):
    global req_seq
    lock.acquire()
    req_seq += 1
    thread_id = threading.current_thread().ident
#    print "thread id = {}".format(thread_id)
    req.seq = req_seq
    sent[thread_id] = req
    lock.release()

    return req

def proxy_mangle_response(res):
    thread_id = threading.current_thread().ident
#    print "Got response for thread_id {}".format(thread_id)
    print "Request: {}".format(sent[thread_id].seq)
    lock.acquire()
    del sent[thread_id]
    lock.release()

    print "Response: {}".format(res)
    return res
```

Comment: Thanks @mhawke, that is a pretty smart solution. Before I got your reply, I made some changes in the proxpy implementation to add req as an argument to the `proxy_mangle_response` method. So now the definition looks like `def proxy_mangle_response(res, req)` 

For that, I had to change the definition of the delegate method to take the req as a parameter too, in core.py. Apart from the fact that this requires changes to the implementation of proxpy itself, do you see any obvious flaws with this approach?

And yes, being familiar with proxpy clearly helps here. :)

Comment: You shouldn't change `proxpy` at all. What happens when the module is updated by the maintainers and you want to update? You will need to maintain a patched version and that's quickly going to become tiresome. On the other hand, you could propose your change (passing the request too to the response handler) to the `proxpy` authors as it might be useful.

Comment: Thanks again @mhawke. I think I'll make the changes you proposed.

Comment: Just one thing @mhawke, the req object does not have any variable `seq`. So how are you assigning to this variable the value of req_seq?

Comment: In the request hander: `req.seq = req_seq`. This creates a new attribute in the `req` object which is then accessed in the response handler.

Comment: Aah I see. I didn't know you could do that in python. More used to Java. Thanks again.